# RazorGenerator, getting started, can't get to run

Tags: razorgenerator

I've created a new project and followed the steps in

http://www.carolynvanslyck.com/blog/2012/09/compile-time-support-for-mvc-views/

It worked, '.generated.cs' files popping out.

I then tried doing the same thing on the main project, but 'Enable-RazorGenerator' failed with Project 'WebControls' is not found. WebControls is the name of a project which is attached and does build but which just holds .cs files.

So I manually changed the .cshtml files to have the custom tool of RazorGenerator, which worked

Finally I hit F5, IISExpress crashes, "Debugging information for 'iisexpress.exe' cannot be found', if I continue anyway Internet Explorer doesn't start

So then I change project to open via IIS, IE doesn't start here either. I can manually open the website by navigating to the url but it acts as though it's still using the cshtml files, i.e. slow to get to the page the first time then faster

Any suggestions on where to look to progress from here?

### Extra info:

I need to progress so made a copy and then removed all the changes from the project via subversion, hence the nuget project and the extension were removed, I now still get the same problem as before, so there must be something in an .suo files or similar, something which doesn't get checked in. Clean/rebuild didn't remove it

A totally separate project is unaffected

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone else, so:

- I noticed that the .csproj file had changed
- Installing razorgenerator changed 2 settings behind the scenes

  From 'Specific Page' to "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application"

  It switched on the Native Code debugging option

I've reverted these 2 and it now seems to work ok, although 'Enable-RazorGenerator' still doesn't work but I can live with that